# I get value fot text-box is undefined

Tags: node.js, pug

I get value of req.body.name is undefined !

anyone please help!!

when i reqest from register.jade to users.js and when i try to console my name value it shows undefined in console

register.jade

```
extends layout

    block content

        form(method='post',action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
            .form-group
                label Name
                input.form-control(name='name',type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')

            input.btn.btn-default(name='submit',type='submit',value='Register')
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You send `POST` request to `/users/register` but you listen `/register`?

Comment: when i reuest yo /register  it gives 404 error